# How to choose the execution order of my HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So, i have a controller with two HttpPost.

My view is made like this

- First you fill the form.
- Then you press the submit (on that submit my action is launched, and this action should display something But.
- The controller is on await when i press because a modal pops and user need to put some information inside it. And then he will press again a button to save those information in database.
- There is the bug. The First controller action should redirect on a page, but it wont because of the second controller action.

So how do i tell the controller to replay the action after i used the saving fonction of the second action ?

Thanks for you help !

Here is my controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ModalContent(ParentModel model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            UserInformationViewModel info = model.UserInformationViewModel;
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var objDatabase = client.GetDatabase("Test");
            var collection = objDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("UsersInformations");
            BsonDocument objDocument = new BsonDocument {
            {"Nom",info.NomUser},
            {"Prenom",info.PrenomUser},
            {"Email",info.EmailUser},
            {"Telephone",info.TelephoneUser},               
            };

            collection.InsertOne(objDocument);
        }

        return null;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionNumber2(ParentModel parentViewModel)
    {
        if (parentViewModel != null)
        {
            List<ObjetTransfert> listeParentObjetsTransferts = new List<ObjetTransfert>();
            ActionNumber2 actionNumber2;
            ConvertParentModelToParentBd(parentViewModel, listeParentObjetsTransferts);
            _confidential.CCP(listeParentObjetsTransferts , out resultatC,
                Enums.E.T);

            //Enregistrer d'abord le resultat en Bd
            resultatC.IdentifiantRC = new Guid().ToString();
            _resultatCS.Create(resultatC);

            Session["ID"] = resultatC.Id;
            return View();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, since i'm using the same parameter for both ActionResult, i Just needed to do this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionNumber2(ParentModel parentViewModel)
{
    if (parentViewModel != null)
    {
        List<ObjetTransfert> listeParentObjetsTransferts = new List<ObjetTransfert>();
        ActionNumber2 actionNumber2;
        ConvertParentModelToParentBd(parentViewModel, listeParentObjetsTransferts);
        _confidential.CCP(listeParentObjetsTransferts , out resultatC,
            Enums.E.T);

        //Enregistrer d'abord le resultat en Bd
        resultatC.IdentifiantRC = new Guid().ToString();
        _resultatCS.Create(resultatC);

        Session["ID"] = resultatC.Id;

        UserInformationViewModel parentViewModel= parentViewModel.UserInformationViewModel;
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var objDatabase = client.GetDatabase("Test");
        var collection = objDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("UsersInformations");
        BsonDocument objDocument = new BsonDocument {
        {"Nom",info.NomUser},
        {"Prenom",info.PrenomUser},
        {"Email",info.EmailUser},
        {"Telephone",info.TelephoneUser},               
        };

        collection.InsertOne(objDocument);
        return View();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Put everything in the same action, since my view is containing both Html.BeginForm.

Simple.